# Android Graphical Layout

Tags: android

I am experimenting with Graphical Layout, the imageView under Image and Media why is its frame  always snapping to left? Can I move it to the center? I can't seem to do that.

Likewise with the Frames of Layout, they are always snapping to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a FrameLayout that fills the screen, then drag an ImageView onto it. Select the view, then click on the Change Gravity dropdown ([image: icon]) and change it to `Center`.